# How to get rid of ^M in log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python. I am using a telnet connection in one file `telnet.py` and logging in another file `debug.py`. But after a successful telnet connection when I looked at the log file, I see `^M` added in every line of log file. Can someone guide me through this to get rid of `^M` in log file? Thanks in advance.

filename: telnet.py

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
cmdout = tn.read_until(b"ogin")
Logging(str(cmdout))
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\r")
```

filename: debug.py

```
LOG_FILE = 'testing.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE, level=logging.DEBUG, format='% 
                    (asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

log = logging.getLogger()
def Logging(msg):
    log.debug(msg)
```

Logfile logs are below:

```
switch login
2019-03-22 11:33:37,623: DEBUG: : Password:
2019-03-22 11:33:37,927: DEBUG:  ^M
^M
Establishing connection...   Please wait.^M
^M
   *****************************************************^M
   *                                                   *^M
   *       Command Line Interface SHell  (CLISH)       *^M
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/remove-m-character-from-log-files You might want to check this out!

Answer (score 2):

When receiving a message, simply trim any `\r\n` and add the `\n` back on.

```
def Logging(msg):
    msg = msg.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n'
    log.debug(msg)
```

If the message could be multiple lines, split and reassemble:

```
def Logging(msg):
    lines = [line.rstrip('\r') for line in msg.split('\n')]
    msg = '\n'.join(lines)
    log.debug(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your log file, and use the `replace` method in python:

```
def remove_caret_m_from_the_old_log_file_and_create_a_new_log_file_without_it():
    # Read the old log file.
    the_file = open("your_log_file.txt", "r")
    initial_content = the_file.read()

    # Remove '^M'.
    desired_content = initial_content.replace('^M', '')

    # Write the new content into a new log file.
    the_new_file = open('your_new_log_file.txt', 'x')
    the_new_file.write(desired_content)
```

Comment: Please close your files after!

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` you can find, and then replace the strings that match with a pattern. `re.sub` does this perfectly well for you.

```
import re 

string = "This is a ^M sample ^M string ^M."
pattern = r'\^M'
res = re.sub(pattern, "", string)

print(res, string)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the regex you want is `'\r'`, not the literal characters `^` and `M`.  This is a common notation for control characters; `^M` is carriage return. But of course, regex is overkill for replacing static strings; simply `string,replace('\r', '')` or if you really want to replace `^M`, `string.replace('^M', '')`